# Applying themes to a control template

Tags: silverlight, themes, controltemplate

Basically my problem so far is I'm modifying the control template to a ComboBox so that it looks the way I want it to. On top of that our entire project is using the ExpressionDark theme. The problem is that when I set the style on the ComboBox so it uses my modified template its ExpressionDark styling gets overridden.

The only solutions I could think of was to try and take out any explicit coloring in the template but that didn't work. There's also the OnApplyTemplate() but I'm not sure how I should use this.

Does anybody has some advice on how I could go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to base your custom Style on the implicit Style applied by the Expression Dark theme. You can only have one implicit Style applied to an element. On top of that, if you set the Style property explicitly then no implicit Style will be applied.

So if you have the implicit Style for the Expression Dark theme:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" ... />
```

And a custom Style like:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ComboBox" ... />
```

And use it like so:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" ... />
```

Then you'd need to change MyStyle to be based on the implicit Style, so it's Setters and Triggers are also applied like so:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" ... />
```

This obviously requires that the implicit Style resource be accessible from where you define your custom Style. If the implicit Style is in the application resources, then you should be good.

EDIT:

Since you are using Silverlight, the `x:Type` part is not supported. You'd need to modify the Expression Dark theme to get this to work.

So if you have the implicit Style for the Expression Dark theme:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" ... />
```

You would need to break it out into two Styles like so:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxBaseStyle" TargetType="ComboBox" ... />
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxBaseStyle}" />
```

Then your custom Style would need to be modified like so:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxBaseStyle}" ... />
```

The implicit Style should not have any Setters in it. Everything should be done in the ComboBoxBaseStyle version.

Comment: I looked at BasedOn earlier, but I didn't think about combining it with x:Type. The problem with this approach however is that I'm using Silverlight :( I mean I could still use the BasedOn property but I think I would need to reference the Style explicitly, but its in an assembly so I'm confused on how I would do this.

Comment: @Matt - Sorry, didn't notice that you had the silverlight tag. The `x:Type` won't work there, obviously. Will update answer.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong here but it's not really working the way I expected... I should also mention that I constructed the Control Template from Expression Blend itself. The Control Template that it made for the ComboBox I am creating has explicitly defined color schemes (lots of gradients, etc...). Honestly it seems like the only way I could get this to work without heavily modifying the control template is to used BasedOn="{somethingExpressionDark}" in (what would be) the ComboBoxBaseStyle.